# How should I write `root` type in the typescript code?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I don't know how to write `root` type

The following code:

```js
class BST {
    // root is `BST.Node`'s instance
    root: ???;
    constructor (key: number, value: any) {
      this.root = new BST.Node(key, value)
    }

    static Node = class {
        key: number
        value: any
        constructor (key: number, value: any) {
          this.key = key
          this.value = value
        }
    }
}

const t = new BST(1, 'data')
console.log(t.root instanceof BST.Node) // expected: true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `InstanceType`:

```
class BST {
  // root is `BST.Node`'s instance
  root: InstanceType<typeof BST.Node>;
  constructor (key: number, value: any) {
    this.root = new BST.Node(key, value)
  }

  static Node = class {
      key: number
      value: any
      constructor (key: number, value: any) {
        this.key = key
        this.value = value
      }
  }
}

const t = new BST(1, 'data')
console.log(t.root instanceof BST.Node) // expected: true
```